# How can I print decimal till N in python?

Tags: python, decimal

```
t=int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    N=int(input())
    a,b=stdin.readline().split()
    z=int(a)/int(b)
    x='{0:.Nf}'.format(z)
    print(x)
```

here I want to print `N` decimal places of `z`, but I am not getting the desired result. Instead I get an error.

Comment: What do you mean with "decimal till N"? Please show example input and output. Have you tried `print(round(z, N))`? Should values be rounded or truncated?

Comment: You might consider using `.split(' /')` so that the numbers can be separated by either a space or a division sign.

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation doesn't work that way. The format-specifier part of the string needs to be a part of the string already -- you can't interpolate into it as part of the format function that uses it.

To do what you want, you need to create the string that will format the fraction first, and then use that.

```
# e.g. N = 5
fstr = "{{0:.{0}f}}".format(N)
print(fstr)
```

The double-braces are to "escape" the braces, i.e. you're telling Python to use it as a literal `{` or `}` instead of interpreting it as a format-string.

This gives you

```
{0:.5f}
```

Then, use `fstr`

```
# e.g. z = 22 / 7
x = fstr.format(z)
print(x)
```

Which gives

```
3.14286
```

Or, you can use the [`round()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp) function to round `z` to `N` decimal places and then print that

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parametrically control the width of your formatting string using N, which is type int, in the middle of a string. Look at this piece of code, that hard-codes the value to 3:

```
thisFloat = 0.12345678
'{0:.3f}'.format(thisFloat)
```

and compare with this additional code:

```
N = 3
fstring = '{0:.'+str(N)+'f}'
fstring.format(thisFloat)
```

Both produce the same output because in the second example, the int N has been cast to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think here, you would have to use the `round()` function.

```py
t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    N = int(input())
    a, b = stdin.readline().split()
    print(round(int(a)/int(b), N))
```